# SignalR notifications for Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor-webassembly

I have Blazor WebAssembly client app and ASPCore WebAPI with Microsoft Identity and I want to send notifications to specific users from server.

My first idea of how to achieve this is to send notification like this:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SendPushNotification(ClaimsPrincipal user, string someNotificationMessage)
    {
        string userGuid = user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

        await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("notification", userGuid, someNotificationMessage);
    }
```

And on client check identity, but I haven't even figured out how to get an Identity on the blazor client.?

But I think there's definitely a better way. Please, can you tell me how I can send notifications to specific users?

Answer (score 2):

SignalR has built in support for invoking methods from a specified client. It therefore by default relies on the Claim of type ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier to distinguish between the different users.

```
await _hubContext.Clients.User(userGuid).SendAsync("notification", someNotificationMessage);
```

To make it work you have to pass the JWT token of the users to the hub when establishing the HubConnection from a Blazor Client Component.

Following services have to be injected into the Razor Component:

```
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@inject IAccessTokenProvider tokenProvider
```

The body of the OnInitializedAsync method in the @code section could look sth like this:

```
if (((await AuthState).User).Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    AccessToken token = new AccessToken();

    (await tokenProvider.RequestAccessToken()).TryGetToken(out token);

    if (token is not null)
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/{hubName}"), options =>
            {
                options.AccessTokenProvider = async () => token.Value;
            })
            .Build();
            await hubConnection.StartAsync();
            hubConnection.On<string>("notification", message => 
               { 
                   snackBar.Add(message, Severity.Info); 
               });
    }
}
```

Comment: But this not work for me. I have this code on my client:
    ` private async Task StartNotificationHub()` 
    {
     _notificationHubConnection = new 
    HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/notificationhub"))
    .Build();

    _notificationHubConnection.On<string>("notification", message =>
    {
    snackBar.Add(message, Severity.Info);
    });
    await _notificationHubConnection.StartAsync();
    }` 

and try to send messages as you posted.

Comment: Thank you, but still not working, AuthState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is true but I don't see any other user information. For example, Name and Claims are null.